# Write name sequence on start state form - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this method:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
            if vals.get('production_type') == 'budgeted':
                vals['name'] = 
self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.budgeted') or '/'
            elif vals.get('production_type') == 'nonbudgeted':
                vals['name'] = 
self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.non_budgeted') or '/'
            elif vals.get('production_type') == 'direct':
                vals['name'] = 
self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.direct') or '/'
        return super(bsi_production_order, self).create(vals)
    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
    production_type = fields.Selection([
            ('budgeted','Budgeted'),
            ('nonbudgeted','Non Budgeted'),
            ('direct','Direct Order'),
        ], string='Type of Order', index=True, copy=False,
        help=" ")
```

This creates a new record depending on `production_type` selection.

Now, this writes the name of the document as soon as it is saved, I have this method for the states:

```
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('confirm','Confirmed'),
        ('inprogress','In progress'),
        ('print_order_inprogress','Print In Progress'),
        ('finished','Finished'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string='State', index=True, copy=False,
    help=" ")
    @api.one
    def prod_start_func(self):
        self.write({'state': 'confirm',})
```

When I save the document, the name of it, is written on save, so, it is on `draft` state by default.

What I need is the name to be written when I actually use the `prod_start_func` method to change the `state` from `draft` to `confirm`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the code from create to the function:

```py
  @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
            # if you don't want name to equal New.
            vals['name'] = '/'
```

And in your function:

```py
    @api.one
    def prod_start_func(self):
        name = '/'
        if self.production_type == 'budgeted':
                name = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.budgeted') or '/'
        elif self.production_type == 'nonbudgeted':
                name = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.non_budgeted') or '/'
        elif self.production_type == 'direct':
                name = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.direct') or '/'

        self.write({
                'state': 'confirm',
                'name' : name,
                })
```

Comment: sorry for my mistake, when you use api.one self have only one record so it's safe to access it's field without loop.

Comment: Hi, thank You, right now it throws me NoneType has no attribute 'id', also, do You think it's possible to write this on the very same 'create' function? or better to follow this method?

Comment: Think I'm gonna open a new question for that error :)

Comment: I think like this is better because if you have to cancel the order you will not lose a value from the sequence for just draft orders